# Django serializers: why does self.fields.pop('field_name') work?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-serializer

Referring to the following link as an example (and plenty of other examples exist elsewhere):
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

It's understood that Django serializer fields are defined typically using a tuple, which is immutable:

```
class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```

However, the accepted way to dynamically change serializer fields involves using a pop (`self.fields.pop(field_name)`)

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

How do fields get defined? Is there a pre-processing step in Django serializers?

Comment: Direct read the source code of  it. `pipenv install djangorestframework;pipenv shell;pipenv open rest_framework`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3fcc076d9124fc202be1a4379b6b753209c7afbe/rest_framework/serializers.py#L354

```
def fields(self):
    """
    A dictionary of {field_name: field_instance}.
    """
    # `fields` is evaluated lazily. We do this to ensure that we don't
    # have issues importing modules that use ModelSerializers as fields,
    # even if Django's app-loading stage has not yet run.
    if not hasattr(self, '_fields'):
        self._fields = BindingDict(self)
        for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
            self._fields[key] = value
    return self._fields
```

> How do fields get defined?

It must be clear now.

> Is there a pre-processing step in Django serializers?

Yes. 
This "step" is called [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)

And `Serializer`s, `Model`s, `Forms` are metaclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the serializer **init** method and set the fields attribute dynamicaly, based on the query params. You can access the request object trouth the context, passed to the serializer.

Here I created a reusable mixin, that does the dynamic fields modification.

from rest_framework import serializers

class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Instantiate the superclass normally
    super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    fields = self.context['request'].QUERY_PARAMS.get('fields')
    if fields:
        fields = fields.split(',')
        # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
        allowed = set(fields)
        existing = set(self.fields.keys())
        for field_name in existing - allowed:
            self.fields.pop(field_name)


class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```